# How can I queue the laravel excel import, on traditional way, and dispatch the job again after the first chunk reading

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

My code: (controller)

```
public function formatCSV(Request $request){
    $filename = $request->input('filename');
    $exported_filename = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME).".csv";
    $export_filepath = 'files/scrubber/output/'.$exported_filename;
    $data = [
        'file_name'       => $filename,
        'header_row'      => 10,
        'start_row'       => 10,
        'unit_sqft_col'   => null,
        'file_path'       => storage_path('app/files/scrubber/') . $filename,
        'export_path'     => $export_filepath,
    ];

    $scrubberJob = (new ScrubberJob($data))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3));
    dispatch($scrubberJob);

    return redirect()->route('scrubbers.index')->with('toast.success','Scrubber job is put into queue, please wait for a while..');
}
```

On the above controller, I am dispatching `ScrubberJob`.

`ScrubberJob`

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Imports\ChunkScrubberImport;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Excel;

class ScrubberJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $data;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $import = new ChunkScrubberImport($this->data);
        Excel::import($import, $this->data['file_path']);
    }
}
```

This job is triggering `ChunkScrubberImport`

`ChunkScrubberImport`

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Exports\ChunkScrubberExport;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithLimit;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStrictNullComparison;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

use Excel;


class ChunkScrubberImport implements ToArray, WithLimit, WithStartRow, WithStrictNullComparison
{
    protected $data;
    public $scrubbed_data;

    public function __construct($data, $scrubbed_data = [])
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->scrubbed_data = $scrubbed_data;
    }

    public function array(Array $rows)
    {
        $this->scrubbed_data = $rows;
        return Excel::store(new ChunkScrubberExport($this->data,$this->scrubbed_data), $this->data['export_path']);
    }

    public function startRow(): int
    {
        return $this->data['start_row'];
    }

    public function limit(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

Now, this import is triggering `ChunkScrubberExport`

`ChunkScrubberExport`

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Helpers\APRHelper;
use App\Models\Scrubber;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStrictNullComparison;


class ChunkScrubberExport implements FromArray,WithStrictNullComparison
{
    use RegistersEventListeners;
    protected $data;
    protected $scrubbed_data;

    public function __construct($data, $scrubbed_data = [])
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->scrubbed_data = $scrubbed_data;
    }
    public function array(): array
    {
        $arr = $this->scrubbed_data;


        $rec_arr = $empty_col = array();
        $empty_col_checked = false;
        foreach ($arr as $ak => $av){
            //only if row is not empty (or filled with null), will get inside if condition
            if(count(array_filter($av)) != 0){
                if(!$empty_col_checked){
                    foreach($av as $k => $v){
                        if($v == ''){
                            $empty_col[] = $k;
                        }
                    }
                    $empty_col_checked = true;
                }
                $rec_arr[] = $av;
            }
        }

        foreach($empty_col as $ek => $ev){
            //get all values from a columns, which don't have value in header row
            //and check if all the values from this particular column is empty
            //if empty unset the columns
            if(empty( array_filter(array_column($rec_arr,$ev))) )
            {
                //unset array keys from whole array
                foreach($rec_arr as &$item) {
                    unset($item[$ev]);
                }
                unset($item);
            }
        }


        foreach ($rec_arr as $ak => $av) {

            foreach ($av as $k => $v) {

                //other stuff

            } //end foreach $av

        } //endforeach $rec_arr



        return $rec_arr;
    }
    public static function afterSheet(AfterSheet $event)
    {
        $active_sheet = $event->sheet->getDelegate();
        $centered_text = [
            'alignment' => [
                'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER, 'vertical' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER
            ]
        ];
        $active_sheet->getParent()->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray($centered_text);

    }
}
```

this is working fine for 1 cycle or fetch, now I have the following questions.

1. After the first cycle, I want to update the `start_row` to `$data['start_row'] + 1000` since 1000 is the limit, but, I don't know what might be the best place to put this one. After 1 cycle I want to trigger, scrubberjob written below
   but with updated `start_row`

```
 $scrubberJob = (new ScrubberJob($data))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3));
 dispatch($scrubberJob);
```

2. Since, on first cycle, the file would already be created since I already know the filename, which is stored in `$data['export_path']`. So, instead of overwriting the old file, I want to append rows to the already existing file from the second cycle.
3. How to detect the end of the file, so that no more ScrubberJob is dispatched.

By the way, I have also seen about `ShouldQueue` in docs but I am not sure if it could provide all the needs I have mentioned here. Or am I just complicating things and should go with `shouldQueue` instead? But still, that might need the solution of my question number 2